# Custom font item in ListView

Tags: android, listview, fonts

I want custom fonts in item listview.

code:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater(getArguments());
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
    TextView tvitem = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvitem);
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
                    "fonts/name.ttf");
    tvitem.setTypeface(tf);
    ImageView imgitem = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgitem);
    tvitem.setText(name[position]);
    imgitem.setImageResource(img[position]);

    return v;
}
```

EXCEPTION:

```
11-18 02:04:31.501: E/AndroidRuntime(18221): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-18 02:04:31.501: E/AndroidRuntime(18221): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-18 02:04:31.501: E/AndroidRuntime(18221):    at com.example.tuvi.MainActivity$GridViewAdapter.getView(MainActivity.java:83)
```

What should I do????

Comment: What line in this code is line 83 of `MainActivity.java`?

Comment: line in 83 is code :Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
                    "fonts/name.ttf");

Comment: Have you downloaded the .ttf file?

Answer (score 0):

create an XML file of a single Item(template) and inflate that xml item in Listview

Comment: I create XML : R.layout.item

Answer (score 0):

> line in 83 is code :Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/name.ttf");

Then `context` is `null`.

Get rid of `context.` and just use `getAssets()`, as you are inside of an `Activity` (otherwise, `getLayoutInflater()` would not work).

Comment: you may helps me fix it ?.